# Translator Text API 3.0: Transliterate

Tags: azure, botframework, postman, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

I have followed this [document](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-transliterate) and tried in postman to check for output by giving these parameters and headers

```
Headers: 
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:****************
Content-Type:application/json
Content-Length:32

Query Params:
api-version:3.0
language:hi
fromScript:Deva
toScript:Latn

body : 
[
    {"Text":"मैं हूँ ना"}
]
```

> {"error":{"code":400000,"message":"One of the request inputs is not
>   valid."}}

I'm not able to get the output. can anyone pls help me here.

Comment: Are you trying on `Code` or `PostMan`

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I'm trying in postman. And I'm able to get the output the thing is In headers **no need of content-length** after removing that i am able to get the output... but in documentation they gave content-length as **required**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in headers no need of content-length

```
Headers: 
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:****************
Content-Type:application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to execute directly on the browser by following the below url,

https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/5155784/RWaEyq9y?version=latest#4e3e8e9b-cdcf-4304-96c9-d4330017e851

You can open up the same request using PostMan in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Your body is an invalid json object. Try remove the square brackets from your body.